# Can not iterate over elements in Jquery

Tags: jquery, iteration

I have function:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if ($(this).attr('href') === ('#' + $('#myTabContent').children('div').attr('id'))) {
                alert($(this).attr('href'));
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

and markup:

```
 <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li><a href="#vergiSK" data-toggle="tab">
        </a></li>
    <li><a href="#spkSK" data-toggle="tab">
        </a></li>
    <li><a href="#hukukSK" data-toggle="tab">
       </a></li>
</ul>
<div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="vergiSK">
     <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li> 
     </ul>
   </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="spkSK">
      <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li> 
     </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="hukukSK">
      <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li> 
     </ul>
    </div>
 </div>
```

The problem is that when I click on one of '**a**' elements I am getting only element with first ID. How can I get all matched '**href**' and values of '**id**'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to get the `div` related to the anchor you're clicking, then:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
            var $div = $($(this).attr("href"));
            // Do something with the div
        });
    });
</script>
```

That works because the value of the `href` you're using (`#vergiSK` and such) is a valid ID selector, so you can pass it directly into `$()` to get a jQuery object wrapped around the element with that ID. Note that I'm using `$(this).attr("href")` to get the `href` rather than just `this.href`, which would be expanded (so would have the full URL, not just the actual content of the `href` attribute).

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/atuwoz/1) (turns the divs red briefly when you click the corresponding link) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/atuwoz/1/edit)

But if for some other reason you want to loop over the elements of `#tab-content`'s children, you'd use [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each).

```
$('#myTabContent').children('div').each(function() {
    // Raw DOM element for each child `div` is `this`
});
```

Comment: That works :) I was trying to match elements with same id value and href attribute and than do some action.